# Why Kruskal clustering generates suboptimal classes?

Tags: algorithm, tree, cluster-analysis, minimum-spanning-tree, kruskals-algorithm

I was trying to develop a clustering algorithm tasked with finding k classes on a set of 2D points, (with k given as input) using use the Kruskal algorithm lightly modified to find k spanning trees instead of one.

I compared my output to a proposed optimum (1) using the rand index, which for k = 7 resulted on 95.5%. The comparison can be seen on the link below.

**Problem:**

The set have 5 clearly spaced clusters that are easily classified by the algorithm, but the results are rather disappointing for k > 5, which is when things start to get tricky. I believe that my algorithm is correct, and maybe the data is particularly bad for a Kruskal approach. Single Linkage Agglomerative Clustering, such as Kruskal's, are known to perform badly at some problems since it reduces the assessment of cluster quality to a single similarity between a pair of points.

The idea of the algorithm is very simple:

- Make a complete graph with the data set, with the weight of the edges
  being the euclidean distance between the pair.
- Sort the edge list by weight.
- For each edge (in order), add it to the spanning forest if it doesn't form a cycle. Stop when all the edges have been traversed or when the remaining forest has k trees.

[image]

**Bottomline:**
Why is the algorithm failing like that? Is it Kruskal's fault? If so, why precisely? Any suggestions to improve the results *without* abandoning Kruskal?

(1): Gionis, A., H. Mannila, and P. Tsaparas, Clustering aggregation. ACM Transactions on
Knowledge Discovery from Data(TKDD),2007.1(1):p.1-30.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is known as **single-link effect**.

Kruskal seems to be a semi-clever way of computing single-linkage clustering. The naive approach for "hierarchical clustering" is `O(n^3)`, and the Kruskal approach should be `O(n^2 log n)` due to having to sort the `n^2` edges.

Note that SLINK can do single-linkage clustering in `O(n^2)` runtime and `O(n)` memory.

Have you tried loading your data set e.g. into [ELKI](http://elki.dbs.ifi.lmu.de/), and compare your result to single-link clustering.

To get bette results, try other linkages (usually in `O(n^3)` runtime) or density-based clustering such as [DBSCAN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBSCAN) (in `O(n^2)` without index, and `O(n log n)` with index). On this toy data set, `epsilon=2` and `minPts=5` should work good.

Answer (score 2):

The bridges between clusters that should be different are a classic example of Kruskal getting things wrong. You might try, for each point, overwriting the shortest distance from that point with the second shortest distance from that point - this might increase the lengths in the bridges without increasing other lengths.

By eye, this looks like something K-means might do well - except for the top left, the clusters are nearly circular.

Comment: I don't think I get it. You suggest I use the second-shortest edge for every pair of points? Wouldn't that result on the same problem? Why Kruskal fails on this sort of problem?

Comment: Kruskal is linking the two blue clusters just because there is a long chain between them. Kruskal often does this. Within a cluster each node has many other nodes close to it. In a long chain each node has just two nodes close by. You could make the chain fail if you could increase the lengths of the links between nodes in a chain enough. You might be able to do this without affecting the links in cluster too much if you replace the length of the 1..kth shortest links to each node with the length of the k+1th shortest link that that node - I thought k=1 but perhaps k=2 would be better.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the manhattan distance but to get better you can try a classic line and circle detection algorithm.

Comment: Why would the manhattan distance help? You're right, shape detection would really boost results up, but I'm supposed to use Kruskal only.